# Doubts about saving SVG files and retrieving

Tags: php, database, json, file, svg

I made a system that a user uploads an Gerber File (Printed circuit board format), and then i convert with PHP that file (GCode), to SVG.

I'm facing a problem now, that is actualy a arquitecture problem.

Shall i save the SVG in a File, or on the Database?

And should i return the SVG as an JSON like ({name: test, data: SVGFILEGOESHERE}) or just render as a .svg? I mean, is JSON safe enough for a BIG data structure?

EDIT:

The Converted SVG will be used in many views in the website, such as: Products pages, configure pages... It's not going to show only one time...

The main idea, is to send a GCode to the server, and once anyone requires that file, if it's not rendered, then it renders, and saves the SVG on the database, or in a file, and store a cache, to avoid re-processing the same file many times.

The SVG, would be retrieved with ajax, and also <s>rendered</s> inserted on the page (but i think i will load everything with ajax).

The file once sent to server, will never be MODIFIED, but can be deleted, and re-sent...

Thanks

Comment: The answer depends greatly on the intended use of your generated SVG.  Would you elaborate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

For what you are doing, I would recommend storing the SVG as a separate file and just returning the SVG as an image (hint: `header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");` in PHP).

As a side note, you said `The SVG, would be retrieved with ajax, and also rendered with PHP on the page.`  This is not quite right; SVG is a text/XML file.  PHP does not render the SVG, it only sends the code of the SVG to the client.  The client machine *must* be the one to parse the SVG code and render it as a visible image to the client.

**Original Answer**

The answer: **it depends**.  You haven't given us much to go on.

SVG is ASCII text, kind of like HTML.  You can learn more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html).  As such, there isn't anything "wrong" with sending an SVG file in JSON, just make sure any quotes are escaped.

JSON is fine for big structures; the issue isn't it's size, it's the time it takes to send it from the server to the client, and then the time it takes for javascript to parse the JSON and render the SVG as an image.  I don't know what your setup is like, or how large the SVG files are, but for very large SVG images, you may want to put them in a separate request that returns only the SVG so the client machine isn't taking time to parse the JSON.  You'll have to do performance testing on your application to see what is best for your needs.

As for storing the SVG as a file or in the Database, it depends on the database, how much memory it has for indexing and how the indexes are built, whether it's SQL or NoSQL, or how much storage space it has, how much traffic you have on the site, how you are backing up the database and/or files, etc etc.  People have used databases to store thumbnails for user images, so it can most definitely hold SVG files in it.  It all depends on how fast and stable the database is.  Personally, I prefer to keep images and large amounts of text in separate files on the hard drive.

Comment: Ease of backup is another consideration: if the SVG files are in the database, they can be backed up along with everything else. That said, I probably wouldn't recommend keeping the SVG files in the database if there was no other reason to do so, just to make taking backups easier.

Comment: Each SVG file, can have up to 10.000 Polyline, Rectangles and also Circles depending on the GCode (Yeah, it's a lot, and i can't "zip" it... GCode !@#!). So, use Files? I'm using Mysql, and i can't be shure of the Cache size on the host...

Comment: I would use files, and then you can just read the file in PHP and output it to the client.  This is pretty fast.  Especially if they are large, make them a separate file.  Don't return them in JSON; that will take the client to long to parse it.  Just return it as an SVG image file. It will be faster (and asynchronous).

Comment: I saved one output of the render, and checked the size. It's like 300kb. I will use Files then... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I said Render, because i use MVC... sometimes it confuses me ^^

Answer (score 1):

It depends on (at least) two things:

1. How you plan on using the data (can it be modified later?)
2. How much traffic the site is going to receive.

If the SVG data can be modified later, I would save it in the database. JSON data should be fine there.

If you think you're going to get a lot of traffic, then I would personally not save it in the database unless you have good caching mechanisms in place. I'm not sure if you're using MySQL, but the query cache in MySQL might not be too happy about caching huge amounts of data.

What I would personally do is save the SVG in a file, and store it in such a way that it can be retrieved based on the associated record in the database, i.e. `/uploads/svg/$username/$circuitboardid.svg`

If you have lots of users (30,000+), your svg directory will get huge and depending on the filesystem you may run into files-per-folder limits.

Comment: I am using a different form of saving files: USERID_PCBID_MD5OFFILE.file, but this is the original, the "cached" SVG would be the same UID (it's not sequencial), as the one in the server

Comment: Are you periodically deleting finished PCB images? If you're storing them all in the same folder, you might encounter slowdowns or filesystem limits like I described above.

Comment: Thanks a point. I think that for now, i will do it as it is, and then do some sort of separation between folders (how and what i'm going to use to separate i don't know yet...)

Comment: I would use the md5 and just split off the first two pairs of characters and use them as folders. E.g. 04/3c/USERID_PCBID_043c...b52d.file The point is to have collisions so you can distribute images into different folders.

Comment: I like it! Should i save the URL of the path to the file, or just the name, and when getting the file i conver it?

Comment: You would only need to save the md5, and you can always figure out the path with that. Implementation is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by using the following code segments in php and mySQL database :
First of all, remember svg is basically stored in text just like HTML is also.  And svg tags, all be it different ones, are laid out very similar to HTML tags.

Storing into the database.  You must use the following code segment in the actual mySQL Insertcall.  I found out if you do this to the variable first and then put the variable in the insert call it will not work.  The function must be in the mySQL statement.
`mysql_real_escape_string($myValue)`

Retrieving Into textbox in value. Assuming your values have been already retrieved from the database and now are in an array Called theValues.  Basically I am Removing any backslashes but before hand I'm making sure it can be displayed correctly using htmlentities. Since you are no Backslashes in  svg that I know of it fixes it where servers replace quotes with \".  If you do encounter some Backslashes in svg you'll just have to be a bit more clever in your replacement function.
 `$myValue= str_replace("\\", "", htmlentities($theValues->myValue)); 
echo $myValue;`

echoing out on to a page same reasons as above, but the htmlentities function Makes it only display the text of the svg Instead of processing the svg And displaying your picture.  this is only required for displaying svg after the text of the Has been stored in a data base but it will not hurt your display If it wasn't the data the first, just A needless function call .
`str_replace("\\", "",$myValue)`